# What's the difference between object's superclass and class's superclass?

Tags: ruby, class, superclass

I get the result:

```
String.class         # => Class 
String.superclass    # => Object 
Class.class          # => Class 
Class.superclass     # => Module
```

Both `String` and `Class` are objects of `Class`. Why is `String`'s superclass `Object` while `Class`'s superclass is `Module`?

Comment: Only classes have superclasses. An "object's superclass" doesn't really make sense (unless that object happens to be a class).

Comment: ...and only one class has no superclass.

Answer (score 0):

You formulate question in a strange way. I have nothing to say besides "they are defined in this way".

```
class A
end

class B
end

class C < A
end

class D < B
end

p C.class # => Class
p C.superclass # => A
p D.class # => Class
p D.superclass # => B
```